# How does "not" function in "I jog nearly every day, not because I like it, but because I am too fat."

Tags: grammar, punctuation, commas, conjunctions

Title. Is it like a conjunction? Also, a few more questions:

1. do you need a comma before the "not"
2. do you need a comma before the "but"

Comment: He went to the store to buy groceries. He went to the store _not_ to buy groceries. Don't separate the _infinitive of purpose_ from the first verb with a comma.

Comment: Relevant: [Synonyms for not-but construction](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319872/synonyms-for-the-not-but-construction)

Comment: Oh sorry my example was bad, see updated title. Basically, the subject of the second phrase is restated (instead of the same as phrase #1), how does that change things?

Comment: "Not because" is ambiguous. Does [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/375752) help?

Comment: It's arguably best not to use a single comma here. None or two.